# Stopping Outlook from being grouped with Windows Explorer in XP Task Bar

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-explorer, taskbar

I've recently upgraded from Outlook 2003 to 2007 and for some reason Outlook is now grouped with Windows Explorer when the Windows Taskbar need to group things:

[image: Weird Windows Taskbar grouping]

I don't want it to do that! Is there anything I can change to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anything to group together you can try this:

```
Right-click "Start Menu"->Properties->"Taskbar" Tab (at top)
->uncheck "Group similar taskbar buttons"
```

I know this is more of a "for the time being" solution, but if you aren't running to many apps this can work just fine as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

TweakUI, one of the [Power Toys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx), includes some options for managing taskbar grouping.  I'm not sure it will fix that problem, but it's worth a look.